# Trying to have a unique number ID in firebase, using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I can't seem to set the counter value to the ID of the last inserted query. It seems to be empty?

```
componentDidMount() {
//Last inserted query
let postRef = firebase.database().ref('clients').orderByKey().limitToLast(1); 
//Fetch the data from the query
postRef.on('value', snapshot => {

  this.setState({ counter: snapshot.child('clients').child('ID').val()});

});


}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no button in the Firebase Realtime Database console to generate a unique ID. If you need this, you will have to build it yourself. Note that the console for Cloud Firestore *does* have such a button, so you might want to consider switching. :-)

Comment: In Cloud Firestore, using the push function, there would be an automated unique id?

Comment: Yes. They're quite different from the `-L...` push IDs from the Realtime Database though, since they're not chronologically ordered.

Comment: I have another question, I was thinking, I think there's a way to keep the counter. Is there a way to get the last inserted push value in real-time firebase?

Comment: That'd be something like `ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)`. In your own code this is trivial using the API. It just doesn't exist in the console.

Comment: let postRef = firebase.database().ref('clients').orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    postRef.on('value', snapshot => {

      this.setState({ counter: snapshot.ID });

    });

Comment: my counter value seems to be empty even if i try to the get the ID, is the the way of doing it?

Comment: Can you open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Unless this question wasn't about doing this in the Firebase console, in which case you should add the code here and I'll reopen it.

Comment: I resubmitted my code, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let postRef = firebase.database().ref('clients').orderByKey().limitToLast(1); 
postRef.once('child_added', snapshot => {
  this.setState({ counter: snapshot.child('ID').val()});
});
```

Changes I made to your code:

- This now uses `once` instead of `on`, because I assume you don't intend to get continuous updates. If you do want to receive updates as keys are added/removed, use `on`.
- I listen for `child_added` since that fires for the correct child node. If you listen for `value` you'll need to loop over the snapshot (with `snapshot.forEach()` to get to the child node.
- I removed the `child('clients')` from your code, since there is no `clients` node under each child.